# The interface class issue in the Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to learn Spring framework. I have some questions.

1. I create one controller and few class. Here is the controller:

   ```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/man")
   public class manController {
       private SwordImp Sword = new SwordImp();
       private GunImp Gun = new GunImp();
       private String mainWeapon;
       private String subWeapon;
       @RequestMapping(value = "set/{weapon:[a-z A-Z 0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String setWeapon(@PathVariable String weapon, Model model){
           System.out.println(weapon);
           if(weapon.equals("gun")){
               Gun.set(weapon);
               mainWeapon = Gun.getWeapon();
               subWeapon = Gun.getSubWeapon();
           }else{
               if(weapon.equals("sword")){
                   Sword.set(weapon);
                   mainWeapon = Sword.getWeapon();
                   subWeapon = Sword.getSubWeapon();
               }else{
                   mainWeapon = "no weapon";
                   subWeapon = "no sub weapon";
               }
           }
           model.addAttribute("weapon_status", mainWeapon);
           model.addAttribute("sub_weapon_status", subWeapon);
           return "man/index";
       }
   }
   ```
2. I also create some class.

   Weapon interface

   ```
   public interface Weapon {
       public void set(String weaponName);
       public String getWeapon();
       public String getSubWeapon();
   }
   ```

   Sword class

   ```
   public class SwordImp implements Weapon {
       private String weaponName = null;   
       public void set(String weapon) {
           this.weaponName = "fire "+weapon;
       }
       public String getWeapon() {
           return this.weaponName;
       }
       public String getSubWeapon() {
           return "no sub weapon";
       }    
   }
   ```

   Gun Class

   ```
   public class GunImp implements Weapon {
       private String weaponName = null;
       private String bullet = null;
       public void set(String weapon) {
           this.weaponName = "ice "+weapon;
           this.bullet = "need bullet";
       }
       public String getWeapon() {
           return this.weaponName;
       }
       public String getSubWeapon() {
           return this.bullet;
       }
   }
   ```

The questions I have:

1. If I don't implement the Weapon class in the gun Class and sword class as below, it seems like that the function still can work... So why do we need to use interface?

   Sword class

   ```
   public class SwordImp {...}
   ```

   Gun Class

   ```
   public class GunImp  {...}
   ```
2. I try to put the all of class into the repositories folder. Is this correct path? or do I need to put them into model folder?
3. At first, I try to put the weaponName variable and bullet variable that in the Gun class and Sword class into the weapon interface, so I don't need to declare them in every class, like this:

   Weapon interface

   ```
   public interface Weapon {
       private String weaponName = null;
       private String bullet = null;
       public void set(String weaponName);
       public String getWeapon();
       public String getSubWeapon();
   }
   ```

   Sword class

   ```
   public class SwordImp implements Weapon {   
       public void set(String weapon) {
           this.weaponName = "fire "+weapon;
           this.bullet = "no sub weapon";
       }
       public String getWeapon() {
           return this.weaponName;
       }
       public String getSubWeapon() {
           return this.bullet;
       }    
   }
   ```

   Gun Class

   ```
   public class GunImp implements Weapon {
       public void set(String weapon) {
           this.weaponName = "ice "+weapon;
           this.bullet = "need bullet";
       }
       public String getWeapon() {
           return this.weaponName;
       }
       public String getSubWeapon() {
           return this.bullet;
       }
   }
   ```

But this seems like that is wrong... what is the reason?

Comment: Please read some theory on OOP. Your understanding of classes and interfaces appears to be very limited, so theoretical discussions on design patterns miss any sense.

Comment: I think it well be useful for you to read some OOP and inversion of control IOC and I think the best thing to understand interfaces uses is to learn some design pattern

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the Abstract factory pattern to inject the specific weapon during runtime rather than hardcoding them in controller.

Consider that you have 100 different weapons,  It will be hard to add all the weapon implementation class to the controller.  You can find the example and implementation of this pattern in google.  It is considered to be a best practice.

2. Try to follow the best practice.  It will help you to learn better and write neat and maintainable code.  yes moving to the model folder is better.
3. In OOP it is important to create your object well defined. Interface can only have the constant fields and methods.  The state defined in the interface cannot be changed.